# Plan 9 from Bell Labs book

Tags: books, plan9

I would really like to obtain a book on Plan 9's design and ethos. Do such things exist?

Anybody have a recommendation?

(Asking here on the basis that Plan 9 was once meant to be Unix's successor, AIUI)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cat-v has a [Plan 9 doc archive](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/) that contains a number of papers, manual pages for various editions and other interesting miscellanea.

Answer (score 8):

[Introduction to Operating Systems abstractions using Plan9 from Bell Labs](http://lsub.org/who/nemo/9.intro.pdf) might be of your interest.

Comment: That book is very poorly edited. Not worth the read in my opinion